# Test for uniformity of a dataset with many ties?

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit, uniform-distribution, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

My goal is to identify images (2D matrix) which are approximately uniform (all same brightness).

Since I don't know of any "natural" tests for uniformity like Shapiro-Wilks for normality, I have tried Earth Mover's Distance and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests.

In each case, I calculate the mean brightness of a given image, then generate an identically-sized, and uniformly-distributed with a little bit of normal noise as the reference to test against.

EMD was too computationally-intensive for my datasets (1024x1024). KS did not work because there were too many ties (identical values) in both the real and reference datasets (which is to be expected).

Is there any way to achieve this? If it matters, I mostly use R, but can work with python as well.

Comment: Until this gets an answer, I'll probably make-do with something like a range of the 5 and 95 percentile brightness data points with respect to the mean.

Comment: If you want goodness-of-fit against the continuous uniform distribution, then many ties in itself is ground for rejection ... why do you want this?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Many images have discrete values, often in 0,1,..., 255.  An image with uniform brightness might exhibit only a handful of distinct values.  The question unfortunately is ill-posed, because it isn't even clear, for instance, that an image with all pixels at 126 and 127 would be considered less or more uniform than an image with all pixels at 254 and 255; nor is it evident whether an image with all pixels at the left equal to 254 and all at the right equal to 255 would be considered "uniform" at all.  We need some characterization of "uniform" to answer this question.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I want to detect uniform layers in a 3D (Z-stacked) image. Those uniform layers are likely to be unwanted noise. If a layer can be robustly detected as being (anomalously) uniform, then it can be marked for further processing.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, those comments seem to be going off on a tangent and are not helpful. A good implementation does not care whether the brightness is at 126, 127, 254, or 254. Or even 69420 for that matter for images differently formatted. A uniform distribution is formally defined in statistics, I'm in need of a useable code implementation to quantify the approximation to it. It puzzles me why you've closed this question, there is nothing more to clarify or define.

Comment: This is no tangent: I am seeking only to understand what you are looking for.  We can't answer a vague or indeterminate question. Indeed, unless all the pixels are constant (one sense of "uniform") or each has an identical pixel count (another sense of "uniform"), your image does *not* define a uniform distribution.  We need you to explain what you mean by "approximately uniform" and how you intend to measure that.

Comment: @whuber "In each case, I calculate the mean brightness of a given image, then generate an identically-sized, and uniformly-distributed with a little bit of normal noise as the reference to test against.", and "I have tried Earth Mover's Distance and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests". This should focus the scope enough, no? I'm open to other methods of "approximating" the uniformity, but closing the question is not helping anyone. Should CV be gatekept to statistics PhDs and every post a rigorous paper to define/prove something, rather than ask questions?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the implications of those statements.  Although I have reopened your question, I still find it vague, because the meaning of "identify" is unclear.  According to your criteria, a matrix of *iid* Normal$(\mu, 1)$ pixels and a matrix of *iid* Normal$(\mu, 100)$ pixels would be equally "uniform" but they certainly would not appear so.  This suggests you haven't fully described what you are trying to do. Moreover, your title refers to "many ties," which is impossible in the reference case you posit. How are we to deal with that inherent contradiction?

Comment: `Should CV be gatekept to statistics PhDs and every post a rigorous paper to define/prove something, rather than ask questions?` - one can understand your frustration, but that is bit of over reaction. What @whuber and others did was to seek clarification, failing to which the post was closed. At CV, any query, irrespective of the level, is answerable provided there is research effort and clarity.